# detailTextLabel on cell created in storyboard with dynamic prototype appears only after cell is selected?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, interface-builder

I am adding cell like below. Before selecting cell, only `textLabel` is able to be seen, after selection `detailTextLabel` getting appear too. Why `detailTextLabel` not on screen from beginning?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ooo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel!.text = "asdf1"
    cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "asdf2"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I changed and changed back in StoryBoard the Table View Cell Style from Right Detail to sth else and select Right Detail again, and set color / highlighted color again

Comment: See [Subtitles of UITableViewCell won't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793074/subtitles-of-uitableviewcell-wont-update).  Looks to be an Apple bug.  You might be able to avoid it if you leave placeholder text in that label in the storyboard, and never set the value to nil yourself.

Comment: no nil, and no empty space allowed, thanks