# UITableViewCell and the case of the missing Subtitle

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I've checked all the usual suspects. I have a UITableView in an iOS 8 app that uses the `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` and sets a subtitle for every cell. I won't bother including code as it's no different from any other code for this. The issue I'm having is best described as follows: my cells also have actions (the new API in iOS 8 lets you add actions to your cells accessible by swiping left on them, similar to Mail). Sometimes (seemingly random), however, the subtitles don't show up unless I swipe on them. Upon swiping, the subtitle appears. Scrolling the cell in and out of view again makes the subtitle disappear until I swipe on it once more. What could be causing this? The subtitle attribute is clearly being set on the cell, it just isn't visible when the cell becomes visible.

Additional info: when troubleshooting, I decided to disable the actions on the cell to see if that was the issue. However, the same problem would occur. Interestingly, with actions disabled, scrolling the cell out and back into view would cause the subtitle to appear.

I'm not unconvinced it's related to this: [Subtitles of UITableViewCell won't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793074/subtitles-of-uitableviewcell-wont-update)

Comment: Is there any chance you are updating your views on a background thread?

Comment: Nope, none at all. Also if that were the case, I believe more than just the subtitle attribute would be missing (the title is set in the same place—the cellForRowAtIndexPath method).

Answer (score 0):

You can chech my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793074/subtitles-of-uitableviewcell-wont-update/26051439#26051439) for a temporary work around. Just put a blank space character in the interface builder inside the subtitle. check the answer for more details.