# UITableViewCell's detailTextLabel disappearing on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am working with a UITableView that uses the standard UITableViewCell. I have the style set to "Right Detail" in Interface Builder.

Each cell looks correct until I scroll it out of the frame and back into the frame, at which point the detail label becomes blank.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("id");

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "value";

    return cell;
}
```

When I call `sizeToFit()`, the label appears again, but overlaps the detail indicator on the right side of the cell.

I gave tried the answers in this question: [UITableViewCell detailTextLabel disappears when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734034/uitableviewcell-detailtextlabel-disappears-when-scrolling), but the only one that works is to subclass the UITableViewCell and I would like to, if possible, not subclass it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but just a tip: replace `self.tableView!` with `tableView` and `cell.detailTextLabel!` with `cell.detailTextLabel?`. Force unwrapping should not be used when you can avoid it without excessive code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`let cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("id");`

Use

`tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("id", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell`

I often had issues with dequeue cells without `indexPath` in previous projects. Not sure why it happens, but it is

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem