# Unable to show detailTextLabel when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, I am simply unable to get a `detailTextLabel` in the `UITableViewCell`.

If I allocate a new `UITableViewCell` each time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the `detailTextLabel` is shown, but obviously I'll get a memory leak this way.

Why is this happening, and how do I manage to show a `detailTextLabel` with reusable cells?

**Update:** I don't use Storyboard and it's a basic system cell. I realise now that `dequeue...` never returns nil, so where am I supposed to configure the cell as style `.Subtitle`?

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        tableView = UITableView(frame: bounds, style: .Plain)
        tableView.delegate   = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    // uses dequeue
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath);
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail NOT displayed"
        return cell
    }

    // doesn't use dequeue...
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // memory leak
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail displayed"
        return cell        
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221003/uitableviewcell-not-showing-detailtextlabel-text-swift

Comment: if the cell you reuse a custom cell or basic system cell?

Comment: The method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns never `nil`, so the if condition is never true. You need to initialize the cell with the appropriate style or use storyboard.

Comment: First, I don't use Storyboard and it's a basic system cell. Now, if `dequeue...` never returns nil, where am I supposed to initialise my cell as a `.Subtitle` style? In `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: The suggested duplicate solution doesn't work (I get no subtitle). I also tried initialising a `UITableView` cell in `viewDidLoad` and dequeue it with the same `reuseIdentifier`. No subtitle then either.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. I removed the `registerClass` line and changed to the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function without the `forIndexPath` argument. Worked instantly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way for "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier".

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell : CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID_CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! CustomCell

    cell.lblData.text = "Text"

    return cell

}
```