# Show contact.phoneNumber into cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contacts

Hello I'm currently working on a contacts application and I can't proper show the contact number into the cell, all I want is to display as a String without the Optional text and the (""). Here is my code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)
    let contact: CNContact!

    if inSearchMode {
        contact = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName) \((contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber)?.stringValue) "

    return cell
}
```

How Could I display the number under the name?

Comment: You should use `CNContactFormatter` to display the name from a contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this `??` [nil-coalescing](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/12/yo-dawg/) operator :

```
"\(contact.givenName ?? "") \(contact.familyName ?? "") \((contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber)?.stringValue ?? "") "
```

Take this example:

```
let s: String? = "Hello"
let newString = s ?? "World" //s is not nil, so it is unwrapped and returned
type(of: newString)          //String.Type
```

If the operand on the left of `??` is nil then the one on its right is returned. the operand on the left of `??` is NOT nil, then it is unwrapped and returned.

```
let s2: String? = nil
let s3 = s ?? "World" //In this case s2 is nil, so "World" is returned
type(of: newString)   //String.Type
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. How can I display it under the name?

Comment: Use the same operator, I am updating the answer

Comment: Thanks for the example. Now how can I return it on the second line?

Comment: You mean you want it as a description?

Comment: Why not use `cell.detailTextLabel.text = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber)?.stringValue ?? ""`

Comment: already tried that with: cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber)?.stringValue ?? "")" and get error

Comment: You'll have to set the style of the cell to have detail labels, either in the storyboard, or [programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221118/2907715)