# Right detail in UITableView not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UIViewController` in which I've embedded `UITableView`. Because I don't want the `UIViewController` to get too heavy I separated the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataSource : UITableViewDataSource!
    var tableDelegate: UITableViewDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = TableViewDataSource()
        tableDelegate = TableViewDelegate()

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = tableDelegate


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}

class TableViewDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return 1
    }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "MyCellIdentifier"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "world"

        return cell
    }
}
class TableViewDelegate : NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    //custom code here if required


}
```

In my Storyboard, I've created a prototype cell within the `UITableView` with the identifier

> MyCellIdentifier

I use this identifier to create a cell in my `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method.

However, if I start the app, only the text of the left label is displayed. The detail label is not visible.

[image]
I looked into the debugger and noticed that detailLabel text is correct. The text of the right label is really "world". However, the label is not visible.
[image]

I've done a little bit of research and there has been [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793074/subtitles-of-uitableviewcell-wont-update/25901083#25901083) in the past. Whenever the text of the detailLabel was set to nil, it was not visible

However in my example, the text is not nil, it is set to "Detail":
[image]

How can I make the right label visible?

Comment: Are you constraints setup correctly?

Comment: Did you already try my suggestion regarding the constraints? Looking at your screenshot it's possible you've put a fixed width on there, which wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: Adding resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: please upload the screen shot of your constraints

Comment: In my case I removed the constraints at some point. With no constraints, the screen got resized and the labels were hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cell != nil)
{
   cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, 
                reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

add this code under let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) this line of your code.

Comment: It will never come inside `if` as it is dequeuing from the storyboard itself. So `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)` will never produce a nil